# Approximate homology of a large simplicial complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, approximation-algorithms, data-analysis, persistent-homology

I can use software to calculate the Betti numbers $\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots$ of a finite simplicial complex.

This is prohibitive for large complexes, built on say > 100,000 nodes.

**Is there some way to computationally approximate the ranks of the first $n$ homology groups?** Results e.g. Carlson [here](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mariom/SHAPE/PAPERS/HOMOLOGY/delaunay.pdf) seem to work only for data points in Euclidean space, where the relations on which the complex is built are interpretations of the data (i.e. persistent homology). I have a set of fixed, deterministic relations on a set of vertices i.e. a graph, and the corresponding clique complex.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'approximate' here?

Comment: I mean to get the Betti numbers, but only “nearly”. Some error is allowed.

Comment: Surely some numerical approximation is available which is inaccurate but quick, converging in some limit to the actual situation?

Comment: You can do mod p homology computations on data of large size. It is a kind of approximation.

Comment: Ok I will look at mod p homology. I'm thinking of getting the Euler characteristic of the clique complex of a sparse complex network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find a way to reduce the size of your simplicial complex. Some algorithms based e.g. on discrete Morse theory can do that fairly rapidly, but they don't have guarantees on the amount of size reduction. I don't think there exists faster algorithms for approximate Betti numbers in general, but I believe it can be done if your simplicial complex is "low-dimensional", meaning that for any point, the size of the sub complex formed by vertices at distance less than $r$ from that point grows slowly with $r$.

Comment: OK I will look at this "lossy compression" idea.

Comment: Those reduction methods typically won't change the homotopy type, so they'll give you exact Betti numbers in fact

Comment: So you can reduce the computation time, without losing information? Like lossless compression?

Comment: yes, these methods reduce the size of the complex without changing the Betti numbers. They are heuristics though, so it's hard to predict how well they will work on a given example.

Comment: So it may not have too much of an effect, if for example the volume expands from a point rapidly

Comment: Actually the volume condition I was mentioning was for a different algorithm that approximates Betti numbers. It shouldn't affect the complex reduction algorithms

Comment: So you get the exact Betti numbers? And it can work on rapidly expanding complexes? Just there is no guarantee it will reduce the computation time effectively.

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Do you recommend a reference I can read?

Comment: http://web.math.ku.dk/~moller/students/brian_brost.pdf seems to have a good state of the art (section 7)